# Difference in ssh user@IP and hostname -i when remote is a Node of Openshift

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote-access

For ex.
When I do

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1
```

and after entering remote host(a node inside Openshift) when I ran the command

```
hostname -i
```

The output of the command was expected to be "192.168.1.1" but it was different IP (it was one from the list I got when I ran

> `hostname -I`

)

Am I missing something here ? Please help!

Comment: What does different mean ?

Comment: What makes you think `hostname -i` is supposed to show 192.168.1.1? 192.168.1.1 isn't the hostname it's the IP address, hostname might be different.

Comment: What does `hostname -I` give you?

Comment: @YisroelTech hostname-I (uppercase i) returns the IP (which I used along with ssh to remotely login i.e. 192.168.1.1) along with bunch of other IPs

Comment: @RohitGupta Edited my question. Sorry for posting it without mentioning vital things

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you got 127.0.0.1?

From the `man` page:

> Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works
> only if the host name can be re‐solved. Avoid using this option; use
> hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.

`hostname -i` requires the hostname of the machine to be resolvable.  If you want to ensure you get see the addresses assigned use `hostname -I` or its equivalent `hostname --all-ip-addresses`.

Alternately, add the name to DNS, host files, or whatever you are using for name resolution.

Comment: The remote machine is basically a node inside Openshift. So I guess it is returning its IP inside that private network

Comment: That would make sense.  You should edit your question to include that vital piece of information.  You can then also post an answer to your own question and accept it.  That is a perfectly acceptable thing to do here.